How to load microfrontends created with create-single-spa with SystemJS?
I created a root-config and parcel in react using create-single-spa: @UJET/test-root-config and @UJET/fruit.  I'm able to view fruit from the root config with a normal dynamic import:
registerApplication({
  name: "@UJET/fruit",
  app: () =>
    import(
      /* webpackIgnore: true */
      "http://localhost:8500/UJET-fruit.js"
    ),
  activeWhen: ["/fruit"],
})


however I want to use SystemJS instead of dynamic import.
switching the import to System.import:
registerApplication({
  name: "@UJET/fruit",
  app: () =>
    System.import(
      /* webpackIgnore: true */
      "http://localhost:8500/UJET-fruit.js"
    ),
  activeWhen: ["/fruit"],
})

adding the global System object in the HTML:
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs/dist/system.min.js"></script>

in the fruit webpack-config:
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const singleSpaDefaults = require("webpack-config-single-spa-react");

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: "UJET",
    projectName: "fruit",
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    output: {
      // Added to output a SystemJS module
      libraryTarget: 'system',
    }
  });
};

This produces the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: application '@UJET/fruit' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Unexpected token 'var' (at UJET-fruit.js:21:10)

From this line in the bundle on line 19:
        execute: function() {
            __WEBPACK_DYNAMIC_EXPORT__(
/******/ var __webpack_modules__ = ({

As you can see the code webpack generated is attempting to define a variable inside a set of parenthesis.  From what I understand this is completely illegal javascript.
Has anyone found their way around this error, or have gotten SystemJS working with single-spa?
Tried adding systemJS to the MFEs generated by create-single-spa.  I was expecting them to work the same as dynamic import does but instead got a very strange error.
